# I have 2 XML documents, identical in structure. If a value in A is different than B, then it needs to be copied to B (or a copy of B)

Tags: c#, xml

I have two XML documents, identical in structure. If a element value in A is different than B, then it needs to be copied to B (or a copy of B).

***UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION***: The element values in A will either be the string "No Change" or something else, indicating a value that needs to be updated in B. That is why I can't just copy the entire document over. If there is "No Change" for an element I don't touch whatever value is already there for the same element in B. If there is anything other than "No Change" then that value gets copied to B. In other words, B's values remain unless there is an updated one in A.

The solution can be using either xmlDocument or XDocument, I'm not particular as long as it works. I'm using **framework 4.0**, so I guess XDocument is the more modern approach.

So it seems logical to me that I would traverse every node/element of document A, and then query the same in B and compare values, and if different, then the A element value gets copied to the same element in B (or a copy of B).

I'm a total newbie with querying XML documents in **C#**, so I thought I'd ask here to save time.

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: I think there's something missing from your question. Why is the solution not "completely overwrite B with A"? I.e. after your process is complete, in what way is B still distinguishable from A?

Comment: I think the thing missing *is* the question

Comment: See edits in question above. Sorry for not being more clear :-)

Comment: When you "equal in structure" does that mean the same number of nodes everywhere and that they are always in the same order?

Answer (score 0):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5?SRC=VSIDE you can transform base XML file to another by this tool 
@edit: and some nice documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to XML (aka `XDocument`, `XElement`, and other related classes) this is actually pretty simple.  In the below code assume that `xmlA` and `xmlB` are two instances of XDocument that are loaded up with your data from xml document A and xml document B respectively:

```
string dataA = xmlA.Element("ROOT_ELEMENT").Element("Element1").Value;
if(!dataA.equals("No Change"))
    xmlB.Element("ROOT_ELEMENT").Element("Element1").Value = dataA;
```

This will check if the value in the element named Element1 under the whatever your root element is named does not have the value of "No Change." If true this will will update the value in the matching element in document B.

EDIT:  To add on an additional example to traverse the whole document and do this for every element:

```
XElement rootElementA = xmlA.Element("ROOT_ELEMENT");
XElement rootElementB = xmlB.Element("ROOT_ELEMENT");
foreach(XElement element in rootElementA.Elements())
{
    if(!element.Value.Equals("No Change"))
    {    
        XElement e = 
               (from el in rootElementB.Elements() 
               where element.Name == el.Name 
               select el).FirstOrDefault();
         e.Value = element.Value;
     }
 }
```

Just keep in mind a few things.  This above example assumes that there is only two levels of elements, the root element and then all elements one level under that.  If your XML goes deeper you will need to use the `HasElements` property for individual elements found in the loop (ie: `if(element.HasElements)` and then create an additional nested loops to dive deeper and deeper into additional levels of elements.

Comment: That covers the capture and copy part when I get to an element in "A", thanks tons for that !...do you have an example of navigating the entire XML "A" document, and then doing that for each element that has a value ?...thanks...Barry

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my post to make it generic, but if these XML Documents are always static and not too long, then it might just be easier to code it directly.

Comment: The XML docs will always be identical in structure, it's just that if there's any value of than "No Change" in the first, it needs to be written to the second. The current size of them is 1900 lines, but they will likely grow in time. Sample to follow...

Comment: (I can't seem to paste a decent sized sample)

Comment: This is the LINQ to XML MSDN guide that should be able to help you as well:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the code update, trying it now...It looks like there's 6 levels deep...

Comment: Turn this into a static method that takes two XElement objects as parameters and then remember recursion is your friend =)

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ...error on the "XElement e =" line, and I assume the "for" was meant to be "foreach" ?

Comment: Ooops sorry about that, yup it should be `foreach`

Comment: It's most likely because the LINQ query has the possibility to return multiple entries since technically you can have the same element name many time.  Try wrapping the query like this:  `(LINQ QUERY).FirstOrDefault()` 
Just be careful to make sure that you are on the right level under the right parent element, otherwise if you have multiple elements with the same name you may overwrite the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on JNYRanger's suggestions, I came up with this last night:

TraverseNodes(xmlSbcCoreData.ChildNodes);

which passes in my XmlDocument object...

```
    private void TraverseNodes(XmlNodeList nodes) {

        Boolean haveValue = false;

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
            // Do something with the node.

            if (!node.Name.Equals("#text")) {
                nodeName = node.Name;
                capturedNode = node;
                haveValue = false;
            } else {
                nodeValue = node.Value;
                haveValue = true;
            }

            if (haveValue) {
                Debug.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
                Debug.WriteLine("GetRecursiveList - capturedNode: " + capturedNode.Name);
                Debug.WriteLine("GetRecursiveList capturedNode Parent: " + capturedNode.ParentNode.Name);
                Debug.WriteLine("GetRecursiveList NAME|VALUE: " + nodeName + " | " + nodeValue);

                string path = getNodePath(capturedNode);
                Debug.WriteLine("GetRecursiveList capturedNode PATH: " + path);

                //THIS IS HOW YOU GET THE NODE IN THE OTHER XML
                XElement element = xmlNbidData.XPathSelectElement(path);
                //AND THEN SET ITS VALUE !!!
                element.Value = nodeValue;
            }

            TraverseNodes(node.ChildNodes);
        }

    }
```

This is the runtime (sample):

---

GetRecursiveList - capturedNode: hraPlan
GetRecursiveList capturedNode Parent: overallDeductible
GetRecursiveList NAME|VALUE: hraPlan | YES

### GetRecursiveList capturedNode PATH: createSbc/createSbcRequest/sbc/coreData/SBCDataContent/importantQuestions/overallDeductible/hraPlan

GetRecursiveList - capturedNode: deductableCrossApply
GetRecursiveList capturedNode Parent: overallDeductible
GetRecursiveList NAME|VALUE: deductableCrossApply | NO

### GetRecursiveList capturedNode PATH: createSbc/createSbcRequest/sbc/coreData/SBCDataContent/importantQuestions/overallDeductible/deductableCrossApply

GetRecursiveList - capturedNode: yearType
GetRecursiveList capturedNode Parent: overallDeductible
GetRecursiveList NAME|VALUE: yearType | CALENDAR

### GetRecursiveList capturedNode PATH: createSbc/createSbcRequest/sbc/coreData/SBCDataContent/importantQuestions/overallDeductible/yearType

GetRecursiveList - capturedNode: individual
GetRecursiveList capturedNode Parent: inNetwork
GetRecursiveList NAME|VALUE: individual | 0

### GetRecursiveList capturedNode PATH: createSbc/createSbcRequest/sbc/coreData/SBCDataContent/importantQuestions/overallDeductible/inNetwork/individual